# Android Facebook Login , get user photos

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to get users profile photo via ;

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture?type=large"
```

I don't have any permission except public profile , email , user friends. 
I want to get users other public pictures and cover photo. How can i get these ? I looked other similar questions but i cannot overcome it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums Will need additional permissions though.

Comment: Is permission need for cover photo too ?

Comment: No, that does not need additional permission.